# The two elements in my div get "lop sided" when I try to format them to fit my specifications

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains two elements.  An Icon `<i>` and a textarea `<textarea>`.
I know exactly how I want this to look and did a quick mock up with the dimensions figured out.
In case my mock up is too sloppy the layout is this.

The div `.container` has a width of 220px and a height of 35px `width: 220px` `height:35px`.

The two elements in the div are to be 4px apart and 4px from the border of the div. (Which I did with padding)

The icon `.fa-plus-square` has a height and width of 27px `font-size: 27px`. (I assumed this sets the width and height to be the same size, but I am unsure.  This may be what is causing the problem)

The textarea `.input` has a width of 181px and a height of 27px `width: 181px` `height: 27px`.

[Div Mock Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o26O7.jpg)

[Whats actually happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g30sH.png) I have colored the add div blue to show you what the elements should be contained in.

Html Code

```html
<div class="add">
    <i class="far fa-plus-square" type="submit"></i>
    <textarea class="input" placeholder="Add to To-Do list"></textarea>
</div>
```

Css

```css
.add {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 220px;
    height: 35px;
}

.fa-plus-square {
    font-size: 27px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    color: rgb(254, 217, 67);
}

.input {
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    resize: none;
    width: 181px;
    height: 27px;
    outline: none;
}
```

Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didnt set the box-sizing property at all.
This is the 1st thing you do, always.
We use box-sizing: border-box 99% of the time, and in some very very rare cases we use others.

A fast fix to your layout.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.add {
    background-color: blue;
    max-width: 220px;
    
    // padding here and dispaly
    padding: 4px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.fa-plus-square {
    margin-right: 4px; // NOTE HERE
    
    font-size: 31px; // the actual size is 4px smaller // dont know why or how
    color: rgb(254, 217, 67);
}

.input {
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="add">
    <i class="far fa-plus-square" type="submit"></i>
    <textarea class="input" placeholder="Add to To-Do list"></textarea>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/ShadiMouma/pen/NWNyWXO?editors=1100

Comment: I will definitely try that, however I did find a fix after posting.  I will post my solution.  But I will also try yours and see which result I like better.

Comment: I tried yours and I'm not gonna bother posting my solution.  It just wasn't as clean and elegant as yours was.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have your icon, so I put an white border to simulate it. Here's the code to achieve something similar to your mock (read the comments):

```css
.add * {
  box-sizing: border-box;     /* For precise calculations */
}

.add {  
    display: flex;            /* Align items in a row, vertically centered */
    align-items: center;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 220px;
    height: 35px;
}

.fa-plus-square {    
    color: rgb(254, 217, 67);
    width: 27px;              /* The next properties are to make */
    max-width: 27px;          /* limit the size of the icon no matter */
    height: 27px;             /* how big the font size. */
    max-height: 27px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    border: 1px solid white;  /* So we can see the icon placeholder */
}

/*
  Needed to add padding to
  the text area
*/
.wrapper {
  padding: 4px;
  flex-grow: 1;     /* Automatic adjustment */
  height: 100%;
}

.input {
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;    /* Adapts automatically in size */
    height: 100%;   /* to what we specified before */
}
```

```html
<div class="add">
    <i class="far fa-plus-square" type="submit"></i>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <textarea class="input" placeholder="Add to To-Do list"></textarea>
  </div>    
</div>
```

The results are precise:

[image]